# Jsfiddle, codepen,Jsbin like front end - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created HTML/CSS/JS playground some well known playground like Jsfiddle, codepen,Jsbin etc.

i would like to know about, "how to save and load the workaround when the user logging in again?" i want user to save their workaround and let them resume from where they stopped.

what approach/idea/possible ways available for this?

do i need to know session/local storage very well?, if not, kindly share your experience. if possible pls share tutorial/example snippets or any other work around.

Note: before asking questions here, i have searched solution as much as i can. but not able to uderstand.

many thanks for any help.

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: @BrianD like using local and session storage. users those who have authorized to access the app. will come under some loop

Comment: Have you tried that? If so, how did it work? Usually people answering questions on Stack Overflow want to see that you've tried to solve the problem yourself. If you show what you've tried already, we can either help you fix your solution or we can suggest alternative things to try.

Comment: what i tried is. (may be am totally wrong). just trying to save some local datas via localstorage with by passing users unique id and storage key. i used to store unique id of user in as some var. then append localstorage key with that var to load data back when user logged in.  i just tried but i dont have snippet with me to share.

Comment: But that should work though. That, or simple cookies/sessions...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the options that you have:

If you want the data to be persistent for users then you need to implement user login and store their data in your database on the backend. That way they will still have it if they log in on a different browser or device.

If you use local storage then it will be saved only for that browser and and every time the user changes the browser the data will be lost.

If you don't want to implement your own backend then you can use something like Firebase or other solutions: see [noBackend](http://nobackend.org/) for more options and more info.

Another option is to use a solution described on [StaticApps](https://staticapps.org/) or [unhosted](http://unhosted.org/) which are very interesting ways to avoid using any backend logic in your apps but still keep some persistent state.

Comment: thanks man.. now understand. from your second point i realized my understanding about local storage is wrong.. now got some clear with point 3 and 4 . thanks alot  ;)